# How does row level security (RLS) interact with traditional GRANT roles

Tags: postgresql, row-level-security

Is a query allowed only when the user has been granted access, and the data returned is the subset that RLS permits?

Comment: [Yes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permissions regulate which databases, schemas, tables and table column a user can access. Row level security adds additional conditions to each statement that determine which rows a user can see or modify.